# Configure boot options in buildroot

Tags: buildroot

How can boot options be configured (specifically looking to add `toram`) in an OS image prepared by [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org)?

The idea is to load the OS completely into RAM, eject the bootable media (SD card in Raspberry Pi Zero) and then run the program that deals with sensitive information so that no trace of that sensitive information can possibly be left anywhere.